# How do you study about software animation?

Tags: animation

This is with reference to the same question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862512/which-programming-language-is-best-for-graphics-programming-closed

Also out of curiosity:

How do they make the cartoon movies in Pixar.  I am sure they use some kind of software animation tools.  Mostly what are they (is it 'Maya' or something much more advanced).
 Also do they do some programming or they use some kind of 3d modeling tools mostly. Are there courses that can be done independently to study those softwares.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with some tutorials

http://www.webreference.com/3d/

You could google "Pixar modeling tutorials/techniques" to get a better feel on the specifics of this.  Here's a link I saw that looked interesting when searching.

http://www.tutorialsphere.com/tutorial/maya-3d/tips-and-techniques/2752/pixar-photorealistic-renderman